# How can I adjust the offset position using Javascript for a smoth scroll?

Tags: javascript

How can I adjust the javascript I have to scroll to an anchor point but also include an offset. I have added a rule for offset of 200px but nothing works.

```
                $('a[href*="#"]')
              .not('[href="#"]')
              .not('[href="#0"]')
              .click(function(event) {
                // On-page links
                if (
                  location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
                  &&
                  location.hostname == this.hostname
                ) {
                  var target = $(this.hash);
                  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                  if (target.length) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html, body').animate({
                      scrollTop: target.offset().top - 200;
                    }, 1000, function() {
                      var $target = $(target);
                      $target.focus();
                      if ($target.is(":focus")) {
                        return false;
                      } else {
                        $target.attr('tabindex','-1');
                        $target.focus();
                      };
                    });
                  }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below snippet for simple example using jquery.

```js
$('a').click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 50
  }, 800, function() {});
});
```

```css
.empty {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

#content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#content">Click Me!</a>
<div class="empty"></div>
<div id="content">
  Content goes here.!
</div>
<div class="empty"></div>
```